# how to add a class as a CLI argument to a jar from the command prompt?

Tags: java, jar, javac

i have an executable jar cli.jar. It takes a class name that extends an abstract class that is present in cli.jar as an argument. I have to implement that class Derived.java.

How do I compile this class in the command line and pass this class as a cli argument to cli.jar?

java -jar cli.jar -class Derived does not work. 
It throws an exception saying ClassNotFound at the line Class.forName(Derived);

To be more clear Derived.java needs cli.jar as its dependency and cli.jar needs takes the class name Derived as one of its parameters.

What are the steps to add this class to the class path, compile it and pass it as a cli argument to the jar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to compile Derived enter javac -classpath path/to/cli.jar Derived.java in command line